# I cant pass token in node js

Tags: node.js, redirect, authorization, token, ejs

I've got problem with redirect system in NodeJS. I created login site, when i'm logging in. When i check if login and password is correct i make jwt token. Then i would like to pass it into another page and redirect("/users/token")to my user page by get method. I searched a lot of sites and I' cant solve this problem. Thank you very much
My code is :

````
    const token = req.params.token;
    console.log("===========================");
    const body = req.body;
    const userId = req.userData.userId;

    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {
        $set: {
            fullname: req.body.fullname,
            university: req.body.university,
            dateofbirth: req.body.dateofbirth,
            studentid: req.body.studentid,
            course: req.body.course,
            // awardeddegree: req.body.awardeddegree,
            // degree: req.body.degree,
            verified: true,
        },

    });
    // .exec()
    // .then(result => {
    // return res.render('forms/verified', {
    //     pageTitle: 'Verification Application',
    //     path: 'form/verified',
    //     formsCSS: true,
    //     productCSS: true,
    //     token:token,

   return res.redirect("/users/token")

}));


router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username.trim();
    const password = req.body.password.trim();
    console.log("sign up Ok!!!!");
    User.find({
        username: username,

    })
        .exec()
        .then(user => {
            if (user.length >= 1) {
                return res.status(errors.USERNAME_UNAVAILABLE.status).json(errors.USERNAME_UNAVAILABLE);
            } else {
                bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        res.status(generalError.status).json(generalError);

                    } else {
                        const user = new User({
                            username: username,
                            password: hash,
                            // fullname:req.body.fullname,
                            // university:req.body.university,
                            // dateofbirth:req.body.dateofbirth,
                            // studentid:req.body.studentid || null,
                            // course:req.body.course,
                            // awardeddegree:req.body.awardeddegree|| null,
                            // degree:req.body.degree|| null


                        });
                        user
                            .save()
                            .then(result => {
                                res.render('forms/login', {
                                    pageTitle: 'Login application',
                                    path: '/forms/login',
                                    formsCSS: true,
                                    productCSS: true,

                                });
                                // res.status(201).json({
                                //     message: "Ο χρήστης δημιουργήθηκε επιτυχώς."
                                //
                                // });
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.log(err);
                                res.status(generalError.status).json(generalError);

                            });
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(generalError.status).json(generalError);

        });

});


////////////////////////
// user login //////////
////////////////////////
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username.trim();
    const password = req.body.password.trim();
    User.findOne({
        username: username
    })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {

                return res.status(errors.USERNAME_CONFIRMATION.status).json(errors.USERNAME_CONFIRMATION);
            }
            //  let fetchedUser = user;
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(authError.status).json(authError);

                }
                if (result) {
                    console.log(user)
                    const token = jwt.sign({
                            username: user.username,
                            userId: user._id,

                        },
                        config.secret
                    );
                    if (user.verified) {
                        if (user.token) {
                            console.log("here")
                            return res.render('forms/main', {
                                pageTitle: 'Verification Form',
                                path: 'form/verified',
                                formsCSS: true,
                                productCSS: true,
                                token: token
                            });
                        }
                        console.log("here2")

                        return res.render('forms/unverified', {
                            pageTitle: 'Main Application',
                            path: 'form/unverified',
                            formsCSS: true,
                            productCSS: true,
                            token: token

                        });

                    }
                    console.log("here 3")

                    return res.render('forms/main', {
                        pageTitle: 'Verification Form',
                        path: '/forms/main',
                        formsCSS: true,
                        productCSS: true,
                        token: token,
                        verify: true


                    });

                    // return res.status(200).json({
                    //     message: "Συνδεθήκατε με επιτυχία",
                    //     username: user.username,
                    //     status: 200,
                    //     success: true,
                    //     token:token,
                    // });
                }
                res.status(authError.status).json(authError);

            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(generalError.status).json(generalError);

        });

});

////////////////////////
// Get all non admin ///
////////////////////////
router.get('/login', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {


    return res.render('forms/login', {
        pageTitle: 'Login Form',
        path: '/forms/login',
        formsCSS: true,
        productCSS: true,

    });
}));

router.get('/registration', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    return res.render('forms/registration', {
        pageTitle: 'Registration Form',
        path: 'form/registration',
        formsCSS: true,
        productCSS: true,

    });


}));
router.post('/main', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log("main")
    return res.render('forms/main', {
        pageTitle: 'Main Application',
        path: 'form/main',
        formsCSS: true,
        productCSS: true,

    });


}));
router.get('/verify', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    return res.render('forms/verified', {
        pageTitle: 'Verified Application',
        path: 'form/verified',
        formsCSS: true,
        productCSS: true,


    });
}));
router.get('/unverified', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    return res.render('forms/unverified', {
        pageTitle: 'unverified Application',
        path: 'form/unverified',
        formsCSS: true,
        productCSS: true,

    });
}));


router.get('/token',verify, asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const _id = req.params._id
    const token = req.params.token;
    let user = await User.findById(_id).exec();


    res.render('forms/token',
        {
            _id: _id,
            // verified: true,
            token: token

        }

    )

    // return res.render('forms/token', {
    //     pageTitle: 'Token Application',
    //     path: 'form/token',
    //     formsCSS: true,
    //     productCSS: true,
    // });
    //res.send({message:"works"})
}));


module.exports = router;```
````

Answer (score 0):

so I see few things which don't add up, return with res object, you don't have to use it if req, res object is in the method already as it is passed here and it reverts to the req it comes with, also in, if conditions I see no else statement
too many res object can also cause errors,
also, I see two login routes in get and post methods, I hope they are in separate sub-route, they cannot be in the same route or sub route even if they have two different methods. Hope this clears doubt's, and about passing the token to the user page I would suggest to render it and pass it as a variable, or if you have to pass it on "get" route u can add it on URL as a query and read the query on the user route, but would not suggest that as it will create vulnerability of token being exposed.
eg. res.redirect("/users/token?token=") //as query

or you can use params to
eg. res.redirect("/users/token/") //as query
and read it as route.get("user/token/:token",(req,res)=>{}